# Will using google apps emailhosting get rid of blacklisting caused by a shared server account?

Tags: email, spam, blacklist

a client`s email addresses are constantly blacklisted due to other users who share the same server. the hoster does want him to switch to his own dedicated server, so he gets his own ip.

my question is:
will moving just his email hosting to google apps get rid of the blacklisting caused by his other users which are on the same server as my client or do i definitely need to move his webapp to his own dedicated server?

i am grateful for any kind of help or suggestions!

Answer (score 3):

You're just moving from one shared hosting infrastructure to another.  Google certainly isn't any better at terminating spammers than some (most?) shared hosting outfits, so you'll still be in a swamp of spammers, but at least Google's big enough that most people don't dare block them for fear of upsetting their customers who suddenly can't receive Aunt Flo's funny cat picture of the day.  So you've got that going for you, at least.

Comment: thanks for your help womble! so the domain`s A Records are still pointing to the ip of the old (blacklisted) server. but the fact alone that the MX-Entries are pointing to google should do the trick?

Comment: You should ask new questions in new questions, not comments on answers to different questions.